# Connect remotely to Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to connect to a MongoDB remotely using Mathematica.

DB Name: http://m0.lmfdb.xyz/

I went to the user mailing list where this code was posted to connect in Python.

from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('m0.lmfdb.xyz', 27017)

client.database_names()

UserName = lmfdb
Password = lmfdb

I am trying to get this code into Mathematica. Here is what I have so far.

MongoConnect[<|"Host" -> "m0.lmfdb.xyz", "Port" -> 27017|>]

I get the following error message:

Message[MongoConnect::mongoliberr, "WL_ClientSimpleCommand", "No 
suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection 
timeout calling ismaster on 'm0.lmfdb.xyz:27017']"]

Can anyone help me with this? I am new to Mongo and appreciate any help in this matter.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Look at: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/MongoLink/tutorial/MongoLinkSimpleTutorial.html  and https://reference.wolfram.com/language/MongoLink/guide/MongoLinkOperations.html

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look. - Chris